# don't want values inserted to text inputs if error message appears

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below I have an jquery with ajax code where it will display change the values of course details by inserting the new data from one set of inputs (the set of inputs where the user has made changes) to another set of inputs (the set of inputs where it states the course's current details). Also the course's drop down menu changes to accommodate the new change if it needs to change:

```
 function submitform() {    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatecourse.php",
        data: $('#updateCourseForm').serialize(),
        success: function(html){
            $("#targetdiv").html(html);
            //Get and store the new course number and name.
                var newCourseNo = jQuery("#newCourseNo").val();
                var newCourseName = jQuery("#newCourseName").val();
                var newDuration = jQuery("#newDuration").val();

                //Set your current course number and name to your number and name.
                jQuery("#currentCourseNo").val(newCourseNo);
                jQuery("#currentCourseName").val(newCourseName);
                jQuery("#currentDuration").val(newDuration);

                //Find the currently selected course and update it.
                var selectedOption = jQuery("#coursesDrop option:selected");
                var label = selectedOption.text().split(" - ");
                selectedOption.text(newCourseNo + " - " + newCourseName);

                $('#targetdiv').show();
        }
     });        
}
```

Now `$("#targetdiv")` is the id where it displays the success or error message retrieved from the php page which is accessed through ajax:

updatecourse.php:

```
...//mysqli code

echo "<span style='color: green'>Course details have been updated:<br/>" . $newcourseno . " - " . $newcoursename . "</span>";

}else{

echo "<span style='color: red'>An error has occured, Course Details have not been updated</span>";

}
```

But the problem I am having is that if the error message from the php code is retrieved in the jquery, then I don't want the course details to make the edit in jquery to accomodate the current course text inputs to insert the new details. I only want that to happen if the success message appears.

If the error message appears I want no change to happen, the current course details inputs and the new course details input simply remain the same before the submit.

But how can this be achieved?

Comment: I would return a json object from the PHP that includes any messages, and a status, whether it was ok or not. if there was an error, don't do any updates, if not, go ahead and do updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get response as JSON (so that you can manipulate the response after you get result...)

try this,

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updatecourse.php",
    data: $('#updateCourseForm').serialize(),
    dataType:'json';  //get response as json
    success: function(result){
        if(result.errorflag){

           //do your stuff on getting error message
          var newHtml="<span style='color: red'>"+result.msg+"</span>" 
          $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here

        }else{
           //you got success message

           var newHtml="<span style='color: green'>"+result.msg+"</span>" 
           $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);
           //Get and store the new course number and name.
            var newCourseNo = jQuery("#newCourseNo").val();
            var newCourseName = jQuery("#newCourseName").val();
            var newDuration = jQuery("#newDuration").val();

            //Set your current course number and name to your number and name.
            jQuery("#currentCourseNo").val(newCourseNo);
            jQuery("#currentCourseName").val(newCourseName);
            jQuery("#currentDuration").val(newDuration);

            //Find the currently selected course and update it.
            var selectedOption = jQuery("#coursesDrop option:selected");
            var label = selectedOption.text().split(" - ");
            selectedOption.text(newCourseNo + " - " + newCourseName);

            $('#targetdiv').show();
         }
      }
 });
```

**PHP**

`json_encode()` to send the reponse as json.... send response as array with the error flag  to check if it is a succcess or error and the msg to print...

```
...//mysqli code

    echo json_encode(array('errorflag'=>false,'msg'=>"Course details have been updated:<br/>" . $newcourseno . " - " . $newcoursename));

  }else{

  echo json_encode(array('errorflag'=>true,'msg'=>"An error has occured, Course Details have not been updated"));

}
```

Comment: Can I quickly ask that if there is an error and I just don't want to change anything, if I just include an empty else, will the page remain the same before the submit? In other words none of the values will move from their inputs?

Comment: yes.. since it is an ajax function..page is not refreshed..so  it should remain same as it was before submit...you can display the error message as i have done for success in error condition...

Comment: thanks... have fun coding... cheers.. and happy new year..:):)

Answer (score 1):

User any flag in the JSON response on the basis of that update the DOM
EX:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatecourse.php",
      dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#updateCourseForm').serialize(),
        success: function(json){
            $("#targetdiv").html(json.htmlContent);
            //Get and store the new course number and name.
        if(json.status=="success"){
 var newCourseNo = jQuery("#newCourseNo").val();
                var newCourseName = jQuery("#newCourseName").val();
                var newDuration = jQuery("#newDuration").val();

                //Set your current course number and name to your number and name.
                jQuery("#currentCourseNo").val(newCourseNo);
                jQuery("#currentCourseName").val(newCourseName);
                jQuery("#currentDuration").val(newDuration);

                //Find the currently selected course and update it.
                var selectedOption = jQuery("#coursesDrop option:selected");
                var label = selectedOption.text().split(" - ");
                selectedOption.text(newCourseNo + " - " + newCourseName);

                $('#targetdiv').show();
}else{
//show whatever mesage u want
}

        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in Success Block

```
success: function(html){
    var indexValue = html.indexOf("An error has occured"); 
    if (parseint(indexValue ) < 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    $("#targetdiv").html(html);
```